# Connecting to a Postgres database using Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, postgresql, windows-phone-8, nuget, npgsql

I've got a remote database (specifically, PostgreSQL) that I need to connect to and do work on from Windows Phone 8. I tried installing npgsql.dll in my solution for the project, but as it turns out, the .dll doesn't seem to be compatible with the version of .NET that Windows Phone 8 uses - it wants .NET 4.5, but apparently, the reduced version that Windows Phone uses doesn't satisfy the install requirements on NuGet.

Google-fu comes up with nothing for me; most of it is about writing to SQLite databases on the device itself.

Comment: Are you trying to directly connect a WP8 application to a remote DB? No 3-tier architecture?

Comment: ken2k, it's for a few class projects. This is sort of a prototype, I suppose, and simpler is better, so I'm going for a direct connection.

Comment: Hmmmmm, we don't have support for WP8 right now. We would need to check our api calls and restrict it to use the WP8 subset. This may take a while. Sorry for that. :( If you have experience with WP8 and would like to help us port Npgsql to run on it, please drop me a mail (francisco at npgsql dot org) or better yet, participate in our user forums: forums.npgsql.org and github: github.com/npgsql/Npgsql Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to write some kind of a web service to encapsulate the PostgreSQL database and make the Windows Phone app communicate with it